# R - Running download.file script in multiple threads

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science

I have to download NYSE historical end of day prices from Yahoo Finance for all stocks in NYSE. This is the working script which is taking almost 20 minutes to download data for 600+ stocks. I have powerful server and would like download these in parallel. How can I do that?

```
for(val in stocks$V1) {
  url <- paste(paste("http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", val, sep=""), "&a=11&b=12&c=1980&d=9&e=28&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv", sep="")
  file_name <- paste(paste("/Users/usdgadiraj/Research/BigData/data/nyse/rscript/", val, sep=""), ".csv", sep="")
  download.file(url, file_name)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `foreach` package and the `%dopar%` function. You will need to use a system-specific parallel backend depending on your OS and from there register your clusters. Please see the following link for more details:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf